# three.js geometry groups incorrect sorting

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image: mesh on the left has the front additive parts rendered first producing incorrect blend]I have a Three.js (r87) scene with modified spine skeletons each with two materials and a buffergeometry with two groups to render both parts of the dynamic mesh.

However, when moving the camera with sorting enabled, the two draw calls sometimes reverse in order creating incorrect rendering due to them both having transparent parts.

After looking at the source code for the WebGLRenderer it looks like **each draw call for the object is entered into the render list at the same depth, therefore the two draw calls fight.**

Spine creates these meshes dynamically for each frame of the animation, layering them from back to front (the additive parts are closer to the camera than the normal parts) which makes them very difficult to split into multiple mesh objects to allow them to be sorted. They are currently one geometry buffer.

Disabling sorting for the entire scene is not really an option. What can I do to preserve the ordering of the draw groups for these objects?

Comment: What is "incorrect rendering"? Is transparency involved?

Comment: yes, both materials are transparent so need to be sorted correctly.

Comment: Also, I've constructed the geometry groups in back to front order each frame specifically so that it renders correctly.

Comment: Is there semi-transparency involved, or is alpha 0 or 1 only? Is the scene static? Is the camera static?

Comment: semi transparency is involved and the scene is heavily dynamic. The camera is mostly static. Depth sorting would work fine if the geometry group order was maintained, but geometry groups seem to have precious little functionality as sorting is based on the object itself. This makes it surprising that the draw groups are then all entered into the render list as separately sortable entries that all share a common depth, this is guaranteed to cause issues surely?

Comment: In your case, avoid geometry groups, create two meshes instead, and use `mesh.renderOrder` to controls the rendering order. You _may_ also have success setting `material.transparent = true; material.depthWrite = false`, depending on your use case.

Comment: thats a real shame, as the number of draw groups changes dynamically with animation each frame, which makes using lots of meshes very difficult...

Comment: if I set sortObjects = false on the renderer, how is the scene rendered? Hierarchy order, or object creation order or some other order?

Comment: Transparent objects are rendered last. You will have to step through with the debugger to see what happens in your particular use case.

Comment: I think a screenshot would really help here...

Comment: I've added a screenshot and some additional explanation. The objects in question are animated spine skeleton meshes.